# UIWebView request.response = nil Issue

Tags: ios, swift, webview, nsurlcache

I'm encountering an issue from `UIWebView` in the `webViewDidFinishLoad` and I'm getting

```
if let urlResponse = NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().cachedResponseForRequest(webView.request!)?.response {

    if (urlResponse as! NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode == 200 {

    }
}
```

as `nil` so I can't check the status code while the body is shown. Please where would be the issue? Is there something I can do from the server side?

Edit: from other requests I can see the response.

Comment: your url is loaded means visible or not

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I'm sorry I didn't understand you, what do you mean by visible or not ?

Comment: Does it happens always ? Or only on some URL ?

Comment: @JulienQuere it happens on some URL's

Comment: your URL is loaded proerly or not

Comment: Are you caching response by calling storeCachedResponse:
              forRequest:?

Comment: @Injectios no I'm not calling storeCachedResponse. Is there something I should do?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the issue. You are checking `NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().cachedResponseForRequest`, but what if the answer is not cached ? If the server explicitly said: "Don't cache this response", the page will be displayed, but not cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think that's because you are checking `NSURLCache` to get your request response. But sometimes, your page can be displayed, but not cached. Indeed, the server can respond something like this:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

It says: "You should absolutely not cache my response". As a good citizen, iOS don't :). So, we have to use a different way to get back the server response. I think the best solution is to use `NSURLSession` to make your request, download the content and forward it to your webview. When the request is made, you will be able to access the answer is the completion handler. Here is an example of what you can do:

```
func loadURL(url: NSURL!) {
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

    let muableRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    muableRequest.setValue("WhateverYouWant", forHTTPHeaderField: "x-YourHeaderField")

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(muableRequest) { (data, response, error) in

        guard error == nil else {
            print("We have an error :( \(error)")
            // Here, you have to handle the error ...
            return
        }

        if let response = response {
            var mimeType = ""
            if response.MIMEType != nil {
                mimeType = response.MIMEType!
            }

            var encoding = ""
            if response.textEncodingName != nil {
                encoding = response.textEncodingName!
            }

            if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                print("HTTP Status code is \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
            }

            self.webView.loadData(data!, MIMEType: mimeType, textEncodingName: encoding, baseURL: url)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

And you call this method like that:

```
loadURL(NSURL(string: "https://apple.com")!)
```

At the place you were doing this before:

```
webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://apple.com")!))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will try it now. 
What I'm getting now is only these two headers.
`Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600`   
`Expires: Thu, 25 Aug 2016 08:44:31 GMT`
Should we add something else from the server?

Comment: Ho, in this case we should use `dataTaskWithRequest` not `dataTaskWithURL`. I just edited my answer to fit your need.

Comment: Yes it is working now, thank you. But could you tell me while the header is returning just Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600 and Expires: Thu, 25 Aug 2016 08:44:31 GMT, should it work?

Comment: Honestly, I dont really know :/. If you found why, I'll be very interested !